# How can I check that I gave the "Get Windows 10" app the right e-mail address?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

When I logged into my Windows 7 machine tonight I got the "Get Windows 10" widget/app/popup thingy.

I gave it my e-mail address and hit the "send confirmation" button, fully expecting to get an e-mail by return of electrons (or at least within a few minutes). However, that didn't happen and I'm still waiting to get the e-mail. I have checked my spam folder, both on my local client and the server but the e-mail's not in either place (that was the first thing I did).

Now the paranoid part of me is starting to think that I must have made a mistake when entering the e-mail address and got something so drastically wrong that I'm never going to get the confirmation.

I don't really want to click the "cancel reservation" button just in case I can't restart the process.

I probably did give it the correct e-mail address (or at least an e-mail that *will* reach me) and there's probably a backlog of e-mails to send. However, how can I assuage that paranoid part of me and check what e-mail address I entered?

Comment: Looks to me you can cancel and re-reserve at any time, but I don't know if doing so will allow you to enter your e-mail address again. Probably not. BTW the e-mail is just so you get confirmation, but won't affect the reservation process itself. The Win10 bits will still be downloaded to your PC over time regardless.

Comment: Check your "spam" folder. ;)

Comment: @w3d done that.

Comment: @Karan - oh - I didn't realise that. I though that you'd have to click a link in the e-mail to download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Windows 10 FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq) states:

> **What happens when I reserve?**
>
> When you reserve, you can confirm your device is compatible with
>   Windows 10. Between reservation and when your upgrade is ready, the
>   files you need for the upgrade will be downloaded to your PC to make
>   the final installation go more quickly. Then, when your upgrade is
>   ready after July 29, 2015, you get a notification that lets you get
>   started with your upgrade.
>
> **How do I get a confirmation that I’ve reserved my upgrade?**
>
> Just click reserve in the Get Windows 10 app and then enter your email
>   address at the confirmation screen.
>
> **You can also check your reservation status here:**
>
> - Right click on the Get Windows 10 app or Windows icon located at the right end of the taskbar.
> - Select “Check your upgrade status”

So if *Check your upgrade status* says you've reserved your upgrade properly, you do not need to worry.